# undefined reference to `inotify_init1'

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, dnsmasq

I am trying to integrate latest [version 2.80 of dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/) application in my project. The platform is Linux 2.6.32. 
Compilation with cross compiler arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc is giving this error:

```
inotify.o: In function `inotify_dnsmasq_init':
inotify.c:(.text+0x514): undefined reference to `inotify_init1'
```

It seems that function inotify_init1() is not supported in this platform.

I'm wondering if I can write this function by myself.

```
int inotify_init1(int flags)
{
    int flags1 = 0;
    int inotify_fd = inotify_init();

    if ((inotify_fd != -1) && (flags != 0)) 
    {
        if((flags1 = fcntl(inotify_fd, F_GETFL)) != -1)
        {
            fcntl(inotify_fd, F_SETFL, flags1 | flags);
        }
    }
    return inotify_fd;
}
```

Would the piece of code do the job?

**Update:**
according to [inotify_init man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_init.2.html), inotify_init1() was added to glibc in version 2.9. I am working with glibc version 2.8 only

In an other hand I see that inotify_init1 is present in several files in Kernel:

```
1) /fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c
/* inotify syscalls */
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(inotify_init1, int, flags)
{ 
...
}
2) /kernel/sys_ni.c
cond_syscall(sys_inotify_init1);
```

I understand that I am missing something but I don't know if the appropriate library is built or properly linked on the dnsmasq building files.

Thank you for advising.

Comment: Do you link to the corresponding library?

Comment: Isn't it is the same library as inotify_init() ?

Comment: i do not know this library but it sounds like you are missing to link the `libwhateveritiscalled.a` to your executable

Comment: As i can read out of [inotify_init man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_init.2.html) you seem to need to link against `glibc`. I am not sure since i do not work as much with linux and its man pages.

Comment: Thank you but according to same inotify_init man page, inotify_init1() was added to glibc in version 2.9. We have version 2.4 only.

Comment: Have you built the library already? There must be some lib file missing or you forget to link it. I can not say for sure since you do not show any code but this is most likely the problem when it comes to undefined reference errors.

Comment: In Kernel file .../fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c I see the following lines 
/* inotify syscalls */
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(inotify_init1, int, flags)
{
...
It is probably the inotify_init1() definition I am looking for. The file is compiled. 
I am not familiar with system calls. How should I call for inotify_init1() in the application code? How to link properly? Thanks.

Comment: Waht warnings do you get? Are you getting "implicit declaration of function inotify_init1" ?

Comment: Yes I get this warning. If I add declaration of the function like this:
extern int inotify_init1 (int __flags) __THROW;
then the warning disappears but still this error remains:
inotify.c:(.text+0x514): undefined reference to `inotify_init1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function looks ok and should work. I don't know however how your application defines the macros IN_NONBLOCK and IN_CLOEXEC. Looking at [kernel srcrs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c#n667) they should be defined the same as O_NONBLOCK and O_CLOEXEC. Also would be nice to add `if (flags & ~(IN_CLOEXEC | IN_NONBLOCK)) return -EINVAL;` some checking.

I would add a file `inotify.h` to your project / to dnsmasq sources, which I would add to include path:

```
#ifndef MY_INOTIFY_H_
#define MY_INOTIFY_H_
#include_next <inotify.h>

// from https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/glibc-2.9/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/inotify.h#L25
/* Flags for the parameter of inotify_init1.  */
enum
  {
    IN_CLOEXEC = 02000000,
#define IN_CLOEXEC IN_CLOEXEC
    IN_NONBLOCK = 04000
#define IN_NONBLOCK IN_NONBLOCK
  };

extern int inotify_init1 (int flags) __THROW;
// or just int inotify_init1(int flags); ...

#endif
```

Along with it your wrapper in a c file added to compilation / linking. The include_next serves as a simple overwrite of the glibc inotify.h.

If you kernel supports inotify_wait1 syscall and I think [it does](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/fs/notify/inotify/inotify_user.c#L656). You can even check if[__NR_inotify_wait1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h#L654) is defined in your unistd.h. You can just:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <sys/syscall.h>

   int inotify_init1(int flags) {
       return syscall(332, flags);
   }
```

To make a syscall just call a syscall() function.

Comment: OK, thank you, let me a chance to check all this later.

Comment: It helps a lot to understand this topic. Thank you.